# How do I connect a client to my DHCP?

Tags: dhcp

I'm new here. I had to create my own DHCP for University project. 
I follow the suggestion and I created it. 
I've a MacBook Pro and I did it on VirtualBox with a machine provided by University.

If on terminal I write `sudo /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server restart` everything works without problems. Now I just want to connect some machines to my DHCP but I don't know how to do. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I connect my VMs through `sudo dhclient -v interface-name`. Also take a look at [VBox Networking Modes](http://packetpushers.net/oracle-virtualbox-network-modes/) to select one in which the DHCP server is visible by the clients.

Comment: Ok thank you so much, now everything works. When I do it this is the message I get

Corrupt lease file - possible data loss.

Then there's DHCPREQUEST and DHCPACK, and the last line is renewal in 112 seconds. 
It seems everything works, I just don't understand why there's corrupt lease file.

Thank you